# Optimización código copiar celdas (vba)

Tags: excel, vba

Buenas,

Necesito programar un código en visual que me copie todas las celdas de un fichero EXCEL a otro, salvo aquellas que están lockeadas en el EXCEL destino. 
El problema es que toda solución que se me ha ocurrido pasa por recorrer celda a celda TODO el fichero, copiando y pegando una a una.
Os podéis imaginar el tiempo de ejecución (los EXCELs son de aproximadamente 5000x50).

Se os ocurre alguna forma para evitar que el codigo recorra una a una?

Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues una forma sería copiar hojas en rangos y luego por cada hoja recorrer las celdas bloqueadas sin necesidad de copiar una a una.

Ahora puedes usar esto:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Rng = ws.Range("A11:D600")
    For Each c In Rng
        If c.Locked = False Then
            c.ClearContents
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Espero te sirva...

La limpieza de las celdas la puede hacer despues de copiar a hoja. Siempre recuerda usar application.screenupdate = false, para que se demore menos el código.

Comment: Lo probaré, gracias!!!